# Push Notifications through Firebase

Tags: push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Yesterday Google has announced a new set of tools for Firebase, one of them was Notifications the ability to send notifications from server to devices which are using my app.

**But can we now notify users when they receive a new message?**

And if not, is there a way around to achieve this?

Comment: If you mean a new message from another user then I was also wondering this. Looking at the documentation, it looks like this is still not possible automatically. I think you'd need to have another server check for each messages sent and then create a notification tagged with the recipient user's ID. Then you subscribe the recipient to it's own user ID tag. Check [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-topics#receive_topic_messages_on_an_android_client_app)

Comment: Great hunting in the docs @user2997154. If you write it up as an answer, I'll upvote. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, this doesn't seem currently possible automatically. Here is a possible way to accomplish it "manually" with another server:

1. Subscribe a user to it's own user ID

In android

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("InsertUserIDHere");
```

In IOS

```
[[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"/topics/InsertUserIDHere"];
```

2. Setup an outside server that checks every sent messages. When a message is sent, the server should create a notification that includes the recipient's user ID as the topic.

Look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-topics#receive-and-handle-topic-messages-with-android) for more info.

Comment: Brilliant !! I have 2 questions if I may. First, how are we going to send notifications using another server, Firebase only allows sending notifications through console. Second, will it be efficient if I have alot of users? The docs say "there may be a delay of as much as one day before new topics are displayed in the console". Thanks.

Comment: Disregard the last comment I made. Look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) for more information on sending messages through a server without the console. I'm not sure if the delay is still applicable if you don't use the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages to group of users (targeting a specific "topic") or to a single device (targeting a Firebase Cloud Messaging token).

To subscribe a device to a topic use:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("topicName");
```

To obtain the device token use (*1) :

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Then you can use the Firebase Notificaitons web console, or the FCM server API if you want to send messages from your server.
See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server

---

**Notes:**

[1] `getToken()` can return null if the token is not yet available.
You can use the callback `onTokenRefresh()` to be notified when the token is available and when the token is rotated.
See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register